# Select only records which have populated value from multiple rows with same reference

Tags: sql

Another newbie question i'm afraid.
I have a data set like the below:

```
Ref     Expiry
A123456 |   21/05/2014
A123456 |   
A123456 |   
A123456 |   21/05/2014
A123456 |   
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
B125962 |   21/05/2014
C236772 |   
C236772 |   21/05/2014
C236772 |   
C236772 |   
C236772 |
```

I want to select only the records that are expired on all rows. So the query should return only B125962 in the data set above.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable
          WHERE Expiry <> ''
          AND Ref = T.Ref)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable
           WHERE Expiry <> ''
           AND Ref = T.Ref)
```

I keep getting no results when using the above.

Thanks!

Comment: Expired mean that Expiry is populated or that it's value is before today?

Comment: Presumably, `expiry` employs a DATE data type?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Ref     
FROM MyTale 
group by Rref
having sum(case when Expiry is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you group by the `Ref` column then you can count how many times the `Expiry` column is empty for each group. Take only the ones where this count is `0`

Comment: I tried this but no joy. I seem to be returning references that are not expired

Comment: @bobtastic - is `Expiry` a nullable column? If so have you tried `... Expiry is null ...` instead of `... Expiry = '' ...` in the above query?

Comment: @bobtastic: What Yawar said. If this is a nullable date column then use `is null` instead of `= ''`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return all occurences of those B125962 records?  If so, this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T
WHERE NOT Ref IN(SELECT Ref FROM MyTable WHERE Expiry = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, considerting the expity column only have value if the row expired,I mean that my assumptopm is that column will not have future expiry date values.

```
SELECT Ref, Expiry FROM MyTable WHERE Ref NOT IN(SELECT Ref FROM MyTable WHERE ISNULL(Expiry,'') = '')
```